# best j2me profiler

Tags: java, mobile, profiler, java-me

which profiler is best for j2me ? there is a profiler in WTK. but it is not good and usefull. JProfiler is good, but I cannot use it for j2me application. is there any profiler like JProfiler for J2ME applications ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Our [SD Java Profiler](http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/Profilers/JavaProfiler.html) is independent of how your development tools and environment works.  You might have to code a tiny profile-data-dump routine, but it should otherwise work just fine with J2ME.

Answer (score 1):

I had always used WTK profiler and never complain about it :)